# Google Cloud Platform: How to make VM continue calculations after disconnecting from the Internet?

Tags: ubuntu, server, google-cloud-platform

I've created VM Instance in Compute Ingeneer with parameters below:

```
Machine type: custom (8 vCPUs, 32 GB memory)
SSD persistent disk: 100GB
Zone: australia-southeast1-b
System: Ubuntu 18.10 (GNU/Linux 4.18.0-1007-gcp x86_64)
```

And I need to make huge calculations on it but there comes a problem that every time I am offline it interrupts. CPU activity falls down.
That is strange cuz it is remote server so I need an opportunity to run it without my machine being connected to the internet and see logs and terminal output after connecting again.

Answer (score 0):

Run your calculations in `screen`.
The most likely it's already installed or available to install on your instance.

On Ubuntu you might install it by executing:
`sudo apt install screen`.